# Receive parameters from Thymleaf page

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have tried to send a parameter from this thymleaf page

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Send Invoice</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="table-row" th:each="p : ${POList}">
            <td th:text="${p.email}"></td> 
            <td>
            <form style='float:left; padding:5px; height:0px' th:object="${p}" th:method="post" th:action="@{/dashboard/makeAndSendInvoice/{email}(email=${p.email})}">

                <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="submit">Send Invoice</button>
            </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

and then I tried to receive the parameter (`email`) using this code

```
@RequestMapping(method=POST, path="/makeAndSendInvoice/{email}")
public void makeAndSendInvoice(@PathVariable("email") String email) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Invoice is sent to..................."+email);

    }
```

The problem is when the value of `p.email`  is something like `myemail@gmail.com`
what I receive in the method `makeAndSendInvoice` is only `myemail@gmail`

and it does not send me the `.com` part

How can I fix it?

Comment: i think you did mistake for your form layout, when you pass email that time have you debug in browser which value is passed?

Answer (score 1):

`(email=${p.email})` means , you are passing a query parameter. 
So, how can you be able to catch the query param value using path variable?

We can use `@RequestParam` to catch the `queryparam` value in Spring

Try the below java code :

```
@RequestMapping(method=POST, path="/makeAndSendInvoice/{email}")
public void makeAndSendInvoice(@RequestParam("email") String email) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Invoice is sent to..................."+email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The period in ".com" will need to be encoded to be used in the url to prevent it being parsed as the suffix

Comment: what if i need a prefix like **.ee**

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Send Invoice</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="table-row" th:each="p : ${POList}">
        <td th:text="${p.email}"></td> 
        <td>
        <form method="post" th:action="@{/dashboard/makeAndSendInvoice/__${p.email}__} ">

            <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="submit">Send Invoice</button>
        </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Your controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard")
@Controller
public class testController {

    ...

    @RequestMapping(value = "/makeAndSendInvoice/{email}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView makeAndSendInvoice(@PathVariable String email, ModelAndView mav) {
       return mav;  // <- Break point, debug !!
    }
}
```